# How to get current date from current timezone from a time server in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift4.2

I am working on application where i want to get current date as per the users current timezone. even after user changes date from their device setting menu.

To get the current timezone i have used

```
let timeZone = TimeZone.current
print(timeZone)
```

for example here i got 'Asia/Kolkata' and current date is 28-july, now if user changes date (Setting->Date&Time-> off set automatically) to 29-july at that time i got output like 'Asia/Kolkata' date 29-july, but actual date is 28-july. so how can i get current date of this (Asia/Kolkata) timezone.

Note: I want to use this because i need current date of particular timezone if user tries to change date from setting then after i need to get exact date from that timezone.

Comment: You have now received to answers that doesn't work for you so this clearly indicates that you need yo improve and clarify your question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ok thank a lot, i make changes in my question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make sure the date is a valid date you can use a timeserver to return the date based on the device IP, of course this will require an internet connection.

You can create a asynchronous method to return the current date regardless of the user timezone and its timezone as well:

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let unixtime: Date
    let timezone: String
}
```

---

```
extension URL {
    static let timeIP = URL(string: "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip")!
    static func asyncTime(completion: @escaping ((Date?, TimeZone?, Error?)-> Void)) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: .timeIP) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil, nil, error)
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
                let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
                completion(root.unixtime, TimeZone(identifier: root.timezone), nil)
            } catch {
                completion(nil, nil, error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
URL.asyncTime { date, timezone, error in
    guard let date = date, let timezone = timezone else {
        print("Error:", error ?? "")
        return
    }
    print("Date:", date.description(with: .current))  // "Date: Tuesday, July 28, 2020 at 4:27:36 AM Brasilia Standard Time\n"
    print("Timezone:", timezone)   // "Timezone: America/Sao_Paulo (current)\n"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution:

```
let timezone = TimeZone.current
let seconds = TimeInterval(timezone.secondsFromGMT(for: Date()))
let date = Date(timeInterval: seconds, since: Date())
print(date)
```

You could simply use `Date()` too, but while using it to display it use `DateFormatter`. Here's an example:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(formattedDate)
```

Comment: if user change the date from setting then after this code gives proper result as per the timezone ?

Comment: Yes, changing the device timezone will be handled.

Comment: sounds great. let me try this

Comment: no this is not working. as i make change from 28 (today date to 29). it gets updated

Comment: How exactly are you updating the time zone?

Comment: i am not updating the timezone. i am just updating the date.

Comment: suppose in Asia/Kolkata timezone today date is 28 right, then user try to change the date from 28 to 29 from the setting so new value display is Asia/Kolkata and date is 29, but actual date is 28.
are you getting my point ?

Comment: Ok, So you're trying to see if the user has updated the date/time, right? I think you missed this point in your post though.

Comment: ok apology for that, but my main question is i want current date as per the current timezone even after user set wrong date or change the date from setting, it should return currentdate as per current timezone

Comment: @TejasPatel you need to use a timeserver

Comment: @LeoDabus how exactly it works? i have never heard about this

Comment: it will return a time based on your IP `"h t t p://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip"`

Comment: @LeoDabus ok let me try for that too.

Answer (score -2):

If you want the current date of the user, you can simply implement `let date = Date()`. It will return the date used on the users device.

This for example will be displayed for me

```
let date = Date() // Jul 28, 2020 at 8:22 AM
var timezone = TimeZone.current // Europe/Berlin (current)
```

Comment: you have not read my question properly.
in this case if user change the date form setting then we get wrong output