# Epoch to Date during the decode

Tags: swift

I have the following json object.

```
{"date" : 1596304900, "name" : "registration"}
```

I have the following struct

```
struct Classroom : Codable{
   let date : Int
   let name : String
}
```

As you see in the json object, `date` is actually epoch time and want to convert it to human readable date during the decode operation. I wonder how it needs to be done during the decode.

Comment: You should look at [`dateDecodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895216-datedecodingstrategy). You can find various examples online, but I might [start here](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `date` a Date instead of an Int, and use a JSONDecoder with its date decoding strategy set to the epoch decoder:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/datedecodingstrategy/secondssince1970

Everything will happen correctly as if by magic. (In the example you've given, the date will turn out to be August 1, 2020, at 18:01:40 GMT.)

Note that this will not be "human-readable"; it will be a *date*. You don't store human-readable; you *show* human readable. You deal with that in the interface only, with a formatter.

Comment: could you please elaborate with an example? I am already applying `decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase`, I do not know where to apply `secondsSince1970`

Comment: @casillas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128051/how-to-get-current-date-from-current-timezone-in-swift/63129033#63129033

Comment: `struct Classroom: Codable {`
   `let date: Date`
   `let name: String`
`}` and `decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970`